# Can I hide specific Google Drive images from Google+ photo?

Tags: google-drive, google-plus, google-plus-photos

I wonder if there are any ways to hide specific GDrive photos from G+ photo even if I turned on the option to show GDrive photos in G+ photo?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean keeping your photos from Google Drive private in Google+ (only accessible to you), that is exactly what happens.

[image: Link Google Drive with Google+]

Specifically you have to share the photo within Google+

> You cannot tag, +1, edit, or comment on Drive photos. To enable these features, share the photo first. Sharing a photo will create and
>   post a copy of the photo-- your original Drive photo will remain
>   intact and your circles will not gain access to your Drive.

You cannot individually select photos in Google Drive not to be shared with Google+. One workaround is to rename your photo files such as `Image0001.jpg.DATA`

[Google Drive and Google+ Photo integration](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3259546?p=photos_drive&hl=en&authuser=0&rd=1)

Comment: Good idea to rename the images. However it is not an ideal solution because it makes them hard to handle in Google Drive and on desktop. I would like to hide all images that I keep in a separate folder. I have not found an easy solution. Maybe the solution is to separate images between different accounts or use more than one cloud service.